# How to extract data from this array in ci

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, associative-array

```
Array ( 
      [0] => Array (
             [name] => Chennai [id] => 98 ) 
      [1] => Array ( 
             [name] => India [id] => 99 ) 
      [2] => Array ( 
             [name] => South India [id] => 100 )
      [3] => Array ( 
             [name] => North India [id] => 101 )
      [4] => Array ( 
             [name] => Delhi [id] => 102 ) 
)
```

This is my array i tried to extract data like this it shows me error

```
foreach ($name as $key => $value) {
    echo $value->name;
}
```

Comment: This is not a codeigniter question this is native PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can change your loop to:

```
     foreach ($name as $key => $value) {
       echo $value['name'];
     }
```

Comment: great... if it would have been a std class object then you could have got the value using your above code.. but since its a pure array you can achieve it through my answer..

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have an array while retrieve it as an object.All your code is perfect except change,

```
foreach ($name as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value['name'];  //you wrote it $value->name which is wrong
}
```